# Check for open tag in textarea

Tags: javascript, input, character

I'm making a Ukrainian phonetic keyboard. People type in English, and the letters automatically change to the corresponding Ukrainian characters. However, when I'm using it, I sometimes need to write myself notes in English (they serve the same purpose as comments in code- for other people and for myself).

I'd like to indicate the start of a comment with a tag ("<"). How can I check if there's currently an open tag?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
if (number of "<" is greater than ">") {//if a tag has been opened and not closed
//disable translation, type in English
}
```

I understand how to disable the translation- however, I'm unsure about the 
"if"

How can I check if

```
number of "<" is greater than ">"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count number of specific characters using .match()

In your case

```
var string = "<<<>>";

if ((string.match(/</g)||[]).length > (string.match(/>/g)||[]).length) {
    console.log("More");
}
else {
    console.log("Less or equal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

counting each of them is like below

```
var countGreaterThan = (temp1.match(/</g) || []).length;
var countLessThan = (temp1.match(/</g) || []).length;
```

and temp is the string value of the textarea

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your data is, you can do:

```
var data = document.querySelector('#data-container').innerHTML;
var isOpenTagPresent = getSymbolCount('<') > getSymbolCount('<');

if(isOpenTagPresent) {
  //execute your logic 
}

function getSymbolCount(symbol) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     if(data[i] === symbol) {
        count++;
     }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers!